# azure download node.js timeout

Tags: node.js, azure

I have the following code running in Azure Functions, (code is from Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229323/node-js-azure-sdk-getblobtostream-uses-lots-of-memory/19249067#19249067)) that most of time downloads large files as it's supposed to. However, sometimes it just stops adding data to the file and never starts again. The bigger the file, the more often it happens. I don't get any errors, nothing. Is there someway to wake the process up again after, say, 10 seconds without progress, or some other way to keep an eye on the process?

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function (context, input) {

context.done();

var accessKey = 'myaccesskey';
var storageAccount = 'mystorageaccount';
var containerName = 'mycontainer';

var blobService = azure.createBlobService(storageAccount, accessKey);

var recordName = "a_large_movie.mov";
var blobName = "standard/mov/" + recordName;

var blobSize;
var chunkSize = (1024 * 512) * 8; // I'm experimenting with this variable
var startPos = 0;
var fullPath = "D:/home/site/wwwroot/myAzureFunction/input/";
var blobProperties = blobService.getBlobProperties(containerName, blobName,   null, function (error, blob) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    else    {
        blobSize = blob.contentLength;
        context.log('Registered length: ' + blobSize);
        fullPath = fullPath + recordName;
        console.log(fullPath);
        doDownload();
    }
}
);

function doDownload() {
var stream = fs.createWriteStream(fullPath, {flags: 'a'});
var endPos = startPos + chunkSize;
if (endPos > blobSize) {
    endPos = blobSize;
    context.log('Reached end of file endPos: ' + endPos);
}

context.log("Downloading " + (endPos - startPos) + " bytes starting from " + startPos + " marker.");

blobService.getBlobToStream(
    containerName, 
    blobName, 
    stream, 
    { 
        "rangeStart": startPos, 
        "rangeEnd": endPos-1 
    }, 
    function(error) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        else if (!error) {
            startPos = endPos;
            if (startPos <= blobSize - 1) {
                doDownload();
            }
        }
    }
);
}

};
```

Comment: Have you tried reducing the chunkSize to 1MB from 4MB?

Comment: Not 1 MB specifically. I started with a chunk size of 512 KB, though, and it gave the same occasional timeout as mentioned above

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri - I changed the chunk to 1MB and it did make it better. However, now and then a large file still times out, so the problem isn't gone. But it did improve it. What's the connection between the chunk size and possible timeouts?

Comment: The chunk size and timeout could be related to your Internet connection. If you have a slow connection, uploading a 4MB chunk will fail while a smaller chunk will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is a short idle timeout on Function apps, so if they don't get requests for 5 minutes the next request, the server will be unloaded.

So, you occurred the issue:

> sometimes it just stops adding data to the file and never starts again. The bigger the file, the more often it happens.

You also can find the suggestion about best practices of Azure Functions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#avoid-large-long-running-functions.

So you can try to use [WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs) as workaround and enable the **Always On** configuration in Application Settings of Azure App Service.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi @Gary - Very interesting about the 5 minutes. However, it seems my download function stops working before the 5 minutes have passed. Is there any way to monitor a process for activity and if nothing has happened in like 30 seconds, resend the request for the chunk or start the download of the file all over again? Also, how would I error log something like this timeout, when there is no error response ?